# Postgres - Generate Series

Tags: sql, postgresql, generate-series

I have a table (tb1) containing a column with the creation date (column A) and with the modification date (column B).

I would like to get an aggregate measure, showing how many records have been created in a given interval and how many have been modified in the same interval.

So far I have tried the following code:

```
Select count(distinct tb.id),dd 
from generate_series ('2015-01-01'::timestamp,'2019-11-01'::timestamp,'1 month'::interval)dd
left join tb on tb.columnA<=dd::date
group by dd
```

The output I receive is fine in the regard that I get the following table

```
dd/count
2015-01-01/ 2
2015-02-01/ 6
2015-03-01/ 10
2015-04-01/ 22
...
```

However, I am wondering, how can I include the information from the second column (columB), so that I see that in 2015-03-01 a total of ten accounts has been created, but for example three of them have been modified.

Is a second query needed or can this be done in the same ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `lateral join` to unpivot the data and aggregate:

```
select gs.dd,
       sum(v.is_create) as create_on_date,
       sum(v.is_update) as update_on_day,
       sum(sum(v.is_create)) over (order by gs.dd) as running_creates,
       sum(sum(v.is_update)) over (order by gs.dd) as running_updates
from generate_series('2015-01-01'::timestamp,'2019-11-01'::timestamp,'1 month'::interval
                    ) gs(dd) left join
     (tb cross join lateral
      (values (tb.updatedon, 0, 1), (createdon, 1, 0)
      ) v(dte, is_update, is_create)
     )
     on v.dte::date = dd::date
group by gs.dd
order by gs.dd;
```

Note that this does not use an inequality in the `on` clause.  Instead, it uses cumulative sums in the `select`.  In general, this is preferable from a performance perspective.

You might want to add `where v.dte is not null` if `updatedon` could be `null`.

Comment: Hi Gordon ! Thank you very much ! I will post some more clarification, because the aggregation does not work properly I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

with regard to your answer. 
Thank you very much.

I have performed the lateral join.

```
select gs.dd,
       sum(v.is_create) as create_on_date,
       sum(v.is_update) as update_on_day,
       sum(sum(v.is_create)) over (order by gs.dd) as running_creates,
       sum(sum(v.is_update)) over (order by gs.dd) as running_updates
from generate_series('2015-01-01'::timestamp,'2019-11-01'::timestamp,'1 month'::interval
                    ) gs(dd) left join
     (tb cross join lateral
      (values (tb.creation_date, 0, 1), (tb.modification_date, 1, 0)
      ) v(dte, is_update, is_create)
     )
     on v.dte::date = dd::date
where v.dte is not null
and tb.gather_stats is not false
group by gs.dd
order by gs.dd;
```

Now I get the following table

[Screenshot with data output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jiNpY.png)

The modification date can be in fact `null`, but unfortunately also the creation date can be `null`.

Taking a look at the raw data, for example there are two records with a modification date, in December 2017 (where the creation date is `null`).

The raw data shows that at least one account has been created in Jan 2018, but is not shown performing this lateral join.